# Node js form submit leads to following error - Error: Cannot POST /

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have added login/registration features to my application. These added features, when used in a separate folder work perfectly, as well as my application on its own. However, adding the login/registration features to my perfectly working application has led me to this error. This would happen when I would type in my details on the login page and click the register button (registering an account) to receive the following message on my browser tab 'Error: Cannot POST /' . I cannot understand why I am getting this error. Here is the code I am working with right now that gets me this errorr. I am new to node js etc so I apologise if this is simple! I am using MongoDB Compass Community as my database. Also, apologies for a lot of code but this is all the code necessary to use my login/registration features.

[Folder/File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgHgt.png)

controllers/employeeController.js

```
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Employee = mongoose.model('Employee');
const Task = require('../models/task');
var User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render("employee/login");
  });

//POST route for updating data
router.post('employee/login', function (req, res, next) {
    // confirm that user typed same password twice
    if (req.body.password !== req.body.passwordConf) {
      var err = new Error('Passwords do not match.');
      err.status = 400;
      res.send("passwords dont match");
      return next(err);
    }

    if (req.body.email &&
      req.body.username &&
      req.body.password &&
      req.body.passwordConf) {

      var userData = {
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
      }

      User.create(userData, function (error, user) {
        if (error) {
          return next(error);
        } else {
          req.session.userId = user._id;
          return res.redirect('/profile');
        }
      });

    } else if (req.body.logemail && req.body.logpassword) {
      User.authenticate(req.body.logemail, req.body.logpassword, function (error, user) {
        if (error || !user) {
          var err = new Error('Wrong email or password.');
          err.status = 401;
          return next(err);
        } else {
          req.session.userId = user._id;
          return res.redirect('/profile');
        }
      });
    } else {
      var err = new Error('All fields required.');
      err.status = 400;
      return next(err);
    }
  })

  // GET route after registering
  router.get('/profile', function (req, res, next) {
    User.findById(req.session.userId)
      .exec(function (error, user) {
        if (error) {
          return next(error);
        } else {
          if (user === null) {
            var err = new Error('Not authorized! Go back!');
            err.status = 400;
            return next(err);
          } else {
            return res.send('<h1>Name: </h1>' + user.username + '<h2>Mail: </h2>' + user.email + '<br><a type="button" href="/logout">Logout</a>')
          }
        }
      });
  });

  // GET for logout logout
  router.get('/logout', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.session) {
      // delete session object
      req.session.destroy(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        } else {
          return res.redirect('/');
        }
      });
    }
  });

module.exports = router;
```

models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});

//authenticate input against database
UserSchema.statics.authenticate = function (email, password, callback) {
  User.findOne({ email: email })
    .exec(function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err)
      } else if (!user) {
        var err = new Error('User not found.');
        err.status = 401;
        return callback(err);
      }
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, result) {
        if (result === true) {
          return callback(null, user);
        } else {
          return callback();
        }
      })
    });
}

//hashing a password before saving it to the database
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  var user = this;
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    user.password = hash;
    next();
  })
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

server.js

```
require('./models/employee.model');
require('./models/task');

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testForAuth', { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify: false }, (err) => {
    if (!err) { console.log('MongoDB Connection Succeeded.') }
    else { console.log('Error in DB connection : ' + err) }
});

var db = mongoose.connection;

//handle mongo error
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
  // we're connected!
});

//use sessions for tracking logins
app.use(session({
  secret: 'work hard',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: db
  })
}));

const employeeController = require('./controllers/employeeController');

var app = express();

//setting up morgan middleware
app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views/'));
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({ extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'mainLayout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/' }));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

//serving blank favicon to keep from throwing 404 errors
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')))

//setting up static path for serving static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Bringing in the routes
const index = require('./routes/index');
const api = require('./routes/api');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', api);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Express server started at port : 3000');
});

app.use('/employee', employeeController.router);
```

views/employee/login.hbs (handlebars)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Register Login with Authentication</title>
<!--Custom Theme files-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Register Login Widget template Responsive, Login form web template,Flat Pricing tables,Flat Drop downs  Sign up Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Login Signup Responsive web template, SmartPhone Compatible web template, free WebDesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyEricsson, Motorola web design" />
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!--web-fonts-->
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura:400,300,500,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--//web-fonts-->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Authentication</h1>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="w3">
            <div class="signin-form profile">
                <h3>Login</h3>

                <div class="login-form">
                    <form action="/" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="logemail" placeholder="E-mail" required="">
                        <input type="password" name="logpassword" placeholder="Password" required="">
                        <div class="tp">
                            <input type="submit" value="LOGIN NOW">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="agile">
            <div class="signin-form profile">
                <h3>Register</h3>

                <div class="login-form">
                    <form id="login" action="/" method="post" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateMyForm();">
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="">
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="">
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required="" >
                        <input type="password" name="passwordConf" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="password_conf" required="">
                        <input type="submit" value="REGISTER">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <p><a href="#"> By clicking register, I agree to your terms</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <!--//signin-form-->    
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var passWordField = document.getElementById('password')
        var passWordConfirmField = document.getElementById('password_conf')
        var form = document.getElementById('login')
        function validateMyForm(){
            if(passWordField.value != passWordConfirmField.value){ 
                alert("Passwords do not match. Please try again.");
            } else {
                form.submit()
            }
        }
    </script>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "These added features, when used in a separate folder work perfectly" do you mean you can register?

Comment: @JorgePires Sorry Jorge! I mean I have a folder, for example, 'loginmongo' which has the controller file, model, server etc and I can run that fine (i can login, register etc etc). However, I have an application that is a combined CRUD and TODO but I want a login/registration feature before going into that application. So two separate applications but combining if that makes sense?

Comment: @JorgePires Also, yeah the code above is me applying the login and registration etc to my other application but got this error. I didnt when I used the login/registration features in their separate folder/different application.

Comment: "This would happen when I would type in my details on the login page and click the register button" where is the registration route?

Comment: I believe it is here `router.post('employee/login', function (req, res, next) `. Right?

Comment: "This would happen when I would type in my details on the login page and click the register button" register and login are two different things. are you sure you are not using the wrong endpoint when you register. Please, show me the template, I believe, handlebars

Comment: @JorgePires I have updated it for you! Yes I am using handlebars and sorry, the login and registration sections are on the same page. Sorry for the wait It is 12 at night for me and I was cooking

Comment: @JorgePires as you can see now, the login.hbs file has both the login and register feature. Furthermore, on the register side, you enter an email, username, password and confirm password and hit the submit button. When I hit this button I get the error explained above, sorry again I should have added it but people before were saying I added too much.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the first slash in the route **post  'employee/login'**

You just have to change this line:

```
router.post('employee/login', function (req, res, next) {
```

To be like that:

```
router.post('/employee/login', function (req, res, next) {
```

this should fix the route.

In your form you must change the action property to point to the route that handles the post request.

```
<form action="/employee/login" method="post">
```

That should fix.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210906/discussion-on-answer-by-danizavtz-node-js-form-submit-leads-to-following-error).